# Running script using at command doesn't work entirely

Tags: bash, shell, at

So I did a bash script that read a file in which are directory numbers and then proceeds to run pgloader over them.

I looks like this

```
#create logs for pgloader
Date=`date +%Y_%m_%d`
LOGS="pgloader_logs_$Date"

touch "$LOGS"

echo "loading files from dat folder"
echo "--------------------------------"
pgloader dat/*.load 2> "$LOGS"

#Read brand numbers from input file
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
 #check if dlnr is valid
 dlnr=$line
  if [[ $dlnr == ???? ]]; then

     echo "loading files from $dlnr folder"
     echo "--------------------------------"

     pgloader $dlnr/*.load 2>> "$LOGS"
  fi
done < "$1"

exit 1
```

The directory where i run it looks like

`0002 0005 0021 ... setUpDB.sh brandsnr`

I run it using `echo "./setUpDB.sh brandsnr >> someFileToGetTheOutput" | at TIME`

The problem is it never runs inside the while for some reason. Is the at command not able to read files ?
Because I tried to use a for loop with a number increment instead of reading from the file but it doesn't run inside it either...

The script works perfectly when I run it myself. I just need to be able to launch it overnight...

Comment: Do you get any errors when `at` runs the script? Since you're not redirecting stderr, you'll probably find this in your mailbox.

Comment: Omg I forgot that `>>` only redirects `stdout`. I don't have mail since it is root that runs it. I just relaunched it with `at now` and I get this error `./setUpDB.sh: 52: ./setUpDB.sh: [[: not found`

Comment: That looks like a shell mismatch, since the `[[` builtin is a bashism. Try adding the shebang line `#!/bin/bash` to the top of your script to make it explicit.

Comment: That's what I figured out. It works now. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I am just stupid. 
It runned using a wrong bash I think, so the `[[` where not recognized.

Adding the `#!/bin/bash` shebang seemed to correct it.

I just forgot that `>>` only redirects `stdout` and couldn't find any errors because of that.